# Every word in a sentence should be inserted in each excel cell

Tags: excel, cell

the sentence is

Please see 20B45 for value B-23
Please see 297CC for value for A-8

I have many number of lines like above sentences. I would like to know how to insert each word in every cell in Excel.

all "Please" should come in A row "see" should come in B row "20B45" should come in C row "for" should come in D row "Value" should come in F row "B-23" should come in G row.

Comment: am not able to find any option for this in excel

Comment: Try `Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Next > tick Space > Finish`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0):

First save your document as a 'Macro-Enabled Workbook'.

Open up VBA by holding Alt+F11. Then click 'Insert'->'Module' and paste the following code...

```
Function getWord(inputString As String, index As Integer)
Dim split() As String
split = VBA.split(inputString, " ")
getWord = split(index - 1)
End Function
```

Then you can use `=getWord(inputString,index)` to output individual words.

---

For example, if A1 stores your string.

`=getWord(A1,1)` will return 'Please'.

`=getWord(A1,2)` will return 'see'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Can you please tell me where do I have to insert "=getWord(inputString,index)"

Comment: OK, lets say A1 stores your string, in A2 enter `=getWord(A1,1)`, then in A3 enter `=getWord(A1,2)`

Comment: When I give =getWord(A1,1) it is saying as "#NAME?" in cell

Comment: Have you clicked save in the VBA window? Otherwise Excel will not be able to find your formula.

Comment: Yes I clicked save and file name is been saved as split.xls

Comment: After that only I received When I give =getWord(A1,1) it is saying as "#NAME? in cell

Comment: ahhh, in order for VBA scripts to work you need to save your file as a 'macro enabled file' which is available in the drop box of the save dialogue. The ending should become .xlsm

Comment: Did you create a new module when you opened VBA?

Comment: Also when you save from an xls to an xlsm Excel seems to remove your code so you need to go back into VBA and add the module again.